# Can I sync data from app to the server even if the app is closed?

Tags: ionic-framework, synchronization, ionic3, data-synchronization

I'm developing an Ionic project that stores data locally when the user is offline (in a SQLite database) and should sync this data when the user gets back online, storing this data in a MySQL database in the server.

I check in the app if the user is online from time to time and I'm using this [Background Mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/) plugin to run the app in background. However, I'm facing some problems. When the user has the app closed and later gets online, the app isn't really running, so I can't send the data to the server. As far as I can tell, this plugin only helps if the user doesn't "clean" the app from memory (by swiping it off from the recent apps list), and even the plugin's author says to "Use the plugin by your own risk!".

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383080/sync-data-with-server-when-app-is-closed) but it doesn't really help my case.

Is there any way that I can sync this data with the server even if the app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with MySql, however with Google Firestore such functionality is very easily implementable. I recommend you give it a try, especially since nonSql databases are beginning to become the new norm.

Comment: I've read about it, but I have to integrate with an existing database, and it'd be a huge effort to migrate right now. If I use Firestore, I would have to use their database, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. However, I still think it would be beneficial for you to work on it on the side if you can. Cloud functioning, offline updates, etc.

Comment: Yes, we are thinking about it in the long run. For now, we're trying to find a way to keep our database, since other web softwares use it. But we're not having much luck in this search =/. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. There are many ways to do it, according to the needs of the project. 
One way could be to store data in LocalStorage, create a service that runs when you open the app to verify if the data has been modified.
Another is using the Ionic Native's BackgrounMode plugin, (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/) and execute a function every one period of time. These are two possible ways, you can share more information about the project to see some best practice.

Comment: Create a service won't help me, because if the user doesn't open the app, the sync will not work. I'm using this plugin now and it has some problems as I said in the question. Do you know another option?

Comment: Hi, in that case you cna use a listener when the app close platform.pause.subscribe(e => {});
Then enable backgroundmode with the Ionic Native BackgroundMode Plugin, and execute a setTimeout function to make them running in Background. Homewer, you can add the function at the app init, because backgroundMode dont work very well

Comment: We are using this strategy now, but as I said, it will not work in some circumstances. We're searching if there is a way to make it work in all scenarios.

Comment: @EvertonLenger Did you find a solution about it? If yes then please help because I am too looking for it. Thanks

Comment: @Hashmi Unfortunately no, we had to use another approach and make some changes in the app's logic to achieve our requirements.